# Select Count usage divided by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I do have a table license_Usage where which works like a log of the usage of licenses in a day

```
ID   User        license    date
1    1            A        22/1/2015
2    1            A        23/1/2015
3    1            B        23/1/2015
4    1            A        24/1/2015
5    2            A        22/2/2015
6    2            A        23/2/2015
7    1            B        23/2/2015
```

Where I want to Count how many licenses a user used in a month, the result should look like:

```
   User          Jan           Feb   
    1             2             1        ...
    2             0             2
```

How can I manage to do that???

Comment: This would be better done in your presentation layer.

Comment: Does your query have a where clause that restricts to a given calendar year? If not are Jan 2014 and Jan 2015 lumped in together? Also are you only counting `A` licenses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `PIVOT` or cross tab query. e.g.

```
SELECT [User],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Month = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Jan,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Month = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Feb,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Month = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Mar
       /*TODO - Fill in other 9 months using above pattern*/
FROM   [license]
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MONTH([date])) AS CA(Month)
WHERE  [date] >= '20150101'
       AND [date] < '20160101'
       AND [license] = 'A'
GROUP  BY [User]
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be0b4/1)

Comment: Hello Martin, thanks for your reply it really helps. What if I did want it to return the day of the month that a user used the most number of licenses instead of the the month usage? it's possible?